# I want to continue this table on multiple pages. need solution

Tags: tables

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{table}[htbp]

    \caption{Literature Review on Personality in Software Engineering}  \label{tab:a}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{l|} *{3}{L|}}
        \hline
        Ref & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Model Used}
        & Approach & Limitation & Goal \\
    \hline


        &  \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{MBTI}}} & \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{FFM}}} & \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{BFI}}} &\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{KTS}}} & \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{BTR}}} &\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{NEO-FFI}}} 
        & \multicolumn{3}{L|}{}  \\[7ex]
        \hline


        [10] & & &\checkmark & & & 
        & Interactive personality profiling approach 
        & Test were based on subjective evidences which may lead to uncertainty.
        & In order to propose a structure for effective software team structure. \\

            \hline


        [20] & & & & & &\checkmark 
        & Quasi-Experiment 
        & This study is conducted with students which leads to ambiguity on difference in nature of students and software engineers.
        & To study the product quality, team climate and Satisfaction of software engineers. \\
        \hline
    [23] & &\checkmark & & & & 
    & Empirical Study  
    & The limitation of the study is that the questions used to examine software engineer's preference do not provide details about software engineers.
    & To find out influences among the emotional intelligence and work preferences. \\
    \hline
    [24] & & &\checkmark & & &
    & OR mathematical programming formulation. 
    & The proposed approach is worthy in medium and small number of groups and teams. As number of groups and projects increases the proposed approach outperform. 
    & This study focuses on Multiple Team Formation Problem (MTFP).The proposed approach focuses on allocating multiple people to multiple groups or teams.   \\
    \hline
    [25] & & & &\checkmark & &
    & Empirical Study
    & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
    & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \hline
    [25] & & & &\checkmark & &
    & Empirical Study
    & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
    & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \hline
    [25] & & & &\checkmark & &
    & Empirical Study
    & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
    & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \hline
    [25] & & & &\checkmark & &
    & Empirical Study
    & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
    & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \hline
    [25] & & & &\checkmark & &
    & Empirical Study
    & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
    & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \hline
    [25] & & & &\checkmark & &
    & Empirical Study
    & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
    & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \hline

    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The package `ltablex` enables `tabularx` tables to be split over several pages. In order to use this, you must also remove the `table` environment, as a single floats can generally not be split over multiple pages. Nevertheless, you might want to rethink your table design in order to get rid of all the unused white space.

Comment: @leandriis how can i use this package for spliting my table to different pages?

Answer (score 4):

Yoou can do that with the `ltablex` package, which brings the functioanlities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. Noye yjay, as with longtable, the caption has to be incorporated to `tabularx`.

```
    \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{ltablex, makecell}
    \newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=0.667\hsize\arraybackslash} X}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hsize=1.333\hsize\arraybackslash} X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

    \begin{document}

    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \settowidth{\rotheadsize}{\theadfont NEO-FFI}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{l|} *{3}{L|}}
    \caption{Literature Review on Personality in Software Engineering} \label{tab:a}\\
        \hline
        Ref & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Model Used}
        & Approach & Limitation & Goal \\
    \hline
         &\rothead{MBTI}
         &\rothead{FFM}
         &\rothead{BFI}
         &\rothead{KTS}
         &\rothead{BTR}
         &\rothead{NEO-FFI}%
        & \multicolumn{3}{L|}{} \\[7ex]
        \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{10}{c}{\tablename~\thetable: Literature Review on Personality in Software Engineering\enspace (continued)}\\[-4.55ex]
    \hline
        Ref & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Model Used}
        & Approach & Limitation & Goal \\
    \hline
   &\rothead{MBTI}
     &\rothead{FFM}
     &\rothead{BFI}
     &\rothead{KTS}
     &\rothead{BTR}
     &\rothead{NEO-FFI}%
     & \multicolumn{3}{L|}{} \\[7ex]
        \hline
    \endhead
        {[10]}& & &\checkmark & & & & Interactive personality profiling approach
        & Test were based on subjective evidences which may lead to uncertainty.
        & In order to propose a structure for effective software team structure. \\
            \hline
        [20] & & & & & & \checkmark & Quasi-Experiment
        & This study is conducted with students which leads to ambiguity on difference in nature of students and software engineers.
        & To study the product quality, team climate and Satisfaction of software engineers. \\
        \hline
    [23] & &\checkmark & & & & & Empirical Study
    & The limitation of the study is that the questions used to examine software engineer's preference do not provide details about software engineers.
    & To find out influences among the emotional intelligence and work preferences. \\
    \hline
    [24] & & &\checkmark & & &
    & OR mathematical programming formulation.
    & The proposed approach is worthy in medium and small number of groups and teams. As number of groups and projects increases the proposed approach outperform.
    & This study focuses on Multiple Team Formation Problem (MTFP).The proposed approach focuses on allocating multiple people to multiple groups or teams. \\
    \hline
    [25] & & & &\checkmark & & & Empirical Study
    & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
    & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \hline
    [25] & & & &\checkmark & & & Empirical Study
    & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
    & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \hline
    [25] & & & &\checkmark & & & Empirical Study
    & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
    & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \hline
    [25] & & & &\checkmark & & & Empirical Study
    & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
    & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \hline
    [25] & & & &\checkmark & & & Empirical Study
    & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
    & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \hline
    [25] & & & &\checkmark & & & Empirical Study
    & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
    & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following contains two possibilities on how to redesign the table in order to fit more content onto one page by getting rid of unused white space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex, makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\settowidth{\rotheadsize}{\theadfont NEO-FFI}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}


    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{l|}lL|}
\caption{Literature Review on Personality in Software Engineering} \label{tab:a}\\
    \hline
    Ref & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Model Used}
    &  Description&\\
\hline
     &\rothead{MBTI}
     &\rothead{FFM}
     &\rothead{BFI}
     &\rothead{KTS}
     &\rothead{BTR}
     &\rothead{NEO-FFI}%
    & \multicolumn{2}{L|}{} \\[7ex]
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{9}{c}{\tablename~\thetable: Literature Review on Personality in Software Engineering\enspace (continued)}\\
\hline
    Ref & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Model Used}
    &  Description\\
\hline
 &\rothead{MBTI}
 &\rothead{FFM}
 &\rothead{BFI}
 &\rothead{KTS}
 &\rothead{BTR}
 &\rothead{NEO-FFI}%
 & \multicolumn{2}{L|}{} \\[7ex]
    \hline
\endhead
    {[10]}& & &\checkmark & &&  & Approach: &Interactive personality profiling approach\\
    &&&&&&& Limitation:& Test were based on subjective evidences which may lead to uncertainty.\\
    &&&&&&&Goal:& In order to propose a structure for effective software team structure. \\
        \hline
    [20] & & & & & & \checkmark & Approach: &  Quasi-Experiment\\
  &&&&&&& Limitations: &  This study is conducted with students which leads to ambiguity on difference in nature of students and software engineers.\\
    &&&&&&& Goal: & To study the product quality, team climate and Satisfaction of software engineers. \\
    \hline
        [23] & &\checkmark & & & & &Approach: & Empirical Study\\
&&&&&&& Limitations: & The limitation of the study is that the questions used to examine software engineer's preference do not provide details about software engineers.\\
&&&&&&& Goal: & To find out influences among the emotional intelligence and work preferences. \\
\hline
[24] & & &\checkmark & & &
& Approach: &OR mathematical programming formulation.\\
   &&&&&&& Limitations: & The proposed approach is worthy in medium and small number of groups and teams. As number of groups and projects increases the proposed approach outperform.\\
&&&&&&& Goal: & This study focuses on Multiple Team Formation Problem (MTFP).The proposed approach focuses on allocating multiple people to multiple groups or teams. \\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & & & Approach:& Empirical Study\\
&&&&&&& Limitations: & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.\\
&&&&&&& Goal: & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
\hline

\end{tabularx}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllL}
  \caption{Literature Review on Personality in Software Engineering} \label{tab:b}\\
  \toprule
   Ref & Model Used &  Description\\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\tablename~\thetable: Literature Review on Personality in Software Engineering\enspace (continued)}\\
  \toprule
  Ref & Model Used &  Description\\
  \midrule
  \endhead
        {[10]}& BFI & Approach: &Interactive personality profiling approach\\
        && Limitation:& Test were based on subjective evidences which may lead to uncertainty.\\
        &&Goal:& In order to propose a structure for effective software team structure. \\
            \midrule            
        {[20]} & NEO-FFI & Approach: &  Quasi-Experiment\\
      && Limitation: &  This study is conducted with students which leads to ambiguity on difference in nature of students and software engineers.\\
        && Goal: & To study the product quality, team climate and Satisfaction of software engineers. \\
        \midrule
            {[23]} & FFM &Approach: & Empirical Study\\
    && Limitation: & The limitation of the study is that the questions used to examine software engineer's preference do not provide details about software engineers.\\
    && Goal: & To find out influences among the emotional intelligence and work preferences. \\
    \midrule
    {[24]} & BFI  & Approach: &OR mathematical programming formulation.\\
       && Limitation: & The proposed approach is worthy in medium and small number of groups and teams. As number of groups and projects increases the proposed approach outperform.\\
&& Goal: & This study focuses on Multiple Team Formation Problem (MTFP).The proposed approach focuses on allocating multiple people to multiple groups or teams. \\
    \midrule
    {[25]} & KTS & Approach:& Empirical Study\\
&& Limitation: & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.\\
&& Goal: & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
    \bottomrule

\end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

[image]