# How to arrange a table on page/my table is exceeded out of the page

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{MBTI}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Attributes\\ /Factors\end{tabular} & Charaters & Measurement Metho                                                                                                                                   & Applications                                                                                                                                                                                         & Ref                                                                          \\ \hline
                                                              &           & \multirow{8}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Philosophy and psychology. Social Sciences.\\ Technology.\\ Science and Arts. Linguistics.\end{tabular}} & \multirow{8}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The measurement method\\  used for MBTI is usually \\ a survey based on 100 que-\\ stions, these questions have \\ two options, Yes and No.\end{tabular}} & \multirow{8}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{[}10{]}\\ {[}11{]}\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{1-2}
                                                              &           &                                                                                                                                                     &                                                                                                                                                                                                      &                                                                              \\ \cline{1-2}
                                                              &           &                                                                                                                                                     &                                                                                                                                                                                                      &                                                                              \\ \cline{1-2}
                                                              &           &                                                                                                                                                     &                                                                                                                                                                                                      &                                                                              \\ \cline{1-2}
                                                              &           &                                                                                                                                                     &                                                                                                                                                                                                      &                                                                              \\ \cline{1-2}
                                                              &           &                                                                                                                                                     &                                                                                                                                                                                                      &                                                                              \\ \cline{1-2}
                                                              &           &                                                                                                                                                     &                                                                                                                                                                                                      &                                                                              \\ \cline{1-2}
                                                              &           &                                                                                                                                                     &                                                                                                                                                                                                      &                                                                              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, instead of instructions on what packages should be added to the preamble, post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates the problem. Things like the document class you are using are essential in these cases.

Comment: Instead of using manual line breaks in table cells, you can also use colum types like `p` or `X`(from `tabularx` ) that allow for automated line breaks (as you already did in [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429306/134144))

Comment: Again, I don't think this is a duplicate. It's not a very well worded question. But the problem he's having here is that he wants multiline cells, and that has led him to adopt a strange tabular in a tabular format. The general question identified as a duplicate is a useful general guide to the sort of things that one can do, but it doesn't provide a specific answer. @Iftikhar it would be a huge help if you could try to make questions specific, with compilable MWEs. Posting lots of similar questions which don't seem to take on board earlier comments may cause frustration.