# how can i solve this problem? my table is not going to the next page

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb,multirow,graphicx} % <-- new
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]

\caption{Literature Review on Personality in Software Engineering}  
\label{tab:a}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{l|} *{3}{L|}}
\hline
Ref & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Model Used}
& Approach & Limitation & Goal \\
\hline


& \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{MBTI}}} 
& \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{FFM}}} 
& \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{BFI}}} 
& \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{KTS}}} 
& \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{BTR}}} 
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{NEO-FFI}}} 
& \multicolumn{3}{L|}{}  \\[7ex]
\hline
[10] & & &\checkmark & & & 
     & Interactive personality profiling approach 
     & Test were based on subjective evidences which may lead to uncertainty.
     & In order to propose a structure for effective software team structure. \\
\hline
[20] & & & & & &\checkmark 
     & Quasi-Experiment 
     & This study is conducted with students which leads to ambiguity on difference in nature of students and software engineers.
     & To study the product quality, team climate and Satisfaction of software engineers. \\
\hline
[23] & &\checkmark & & & & 
& Empirical Study  
& The limitation of the study is that the questions used to examine software engineer's preference do not provide details about software engineers.
& To find out influences among the emotional intelligence and work preferences. \\
\hline
[24] & & &\checkmark & & &
& OR mathematical programming formulation. 
& The proposed approach is worthy in medium and small number of groups and teams. As number of groups and projects increases the proposed approach outperform. 
& This study focuses on Multiple Team Formation Problem (MTFP).The proposed approach focuses on allocating multiple people to multiple groups or teams.   \\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & &
& Empirical Study
& They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
& o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & &
& Empirical Study
& They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
& o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & &
& Empirical Study
& They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
& o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & &
& Empirical Study
& They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
& o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & &
& Empirical Study
& They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
& o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & &
& Empirical Study
& They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
& o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: every time you post a fragment that no one can run to debug the problem. Please always post a complete small test document. but neither a `tabularx` nor `table` enviornment ever breaks over a page. You need an enviornment such as `longtable` (or `ltablex` package redefines tabularx to b elongtable but if you put it in a `table` it can not break over a page)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for inconvenience. I have updated the code. please help me out.

Comment: @IftikharAhmad The code is still incomplete - you are missing `\begin{document}` and a curly brace at the end of your code.

Comment: Advice: **(1)** Read this https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. **(2)** Copy and paste the code that you provide here into a new document and try to compile it *before* posting it here (common mistake, I also run it myself).

Comment: your test document does not produce the image shown, it makes the error `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...@tempdima \@parboxrestore \multirow `

Comment: You have broken the `\end{document` line (that I had previously fixed) please fix it again so people can run your example.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429331/36296 shows you how to split a table over multiple pages

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to make it compilable. (Mostly, three extra packages had to be loaded.)

Answer (score 0):

By design, `table` and `tabularx` environments cannot span more than a page. I sugges you load the `longtable` package and employ a `longtable` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,longtable,ragged2e}
\usepackage{array,amssymb,multirow,graphicx} % <-- new
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}

\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{|*{7}{l|} *{3}{P{0.19}|}} % "0.19": found by trial and error

%% header and footer blocks
\caption{Literature Review on Personality in Software Engineering} \label{tab:a} \\
\hline
Ref & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Model Used}
& Approach & Limitation & Goal \\
\hline
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{MBTI}}}
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{FFM}}}
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{BFI}}}
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{KTS}}}
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{BTR}}}
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{NEO-FFI}}}
&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}  \\[7ex]
\hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Table \ref{tab:a}, continued}\\[1ex]
\hline
Ref & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Model Used}
& Approach & Limitation & Goal \\
\hline
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{MBTI}}}
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{FFM}}}
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{BFI}}}
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{KTS}}}
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{BTR}}}
&\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{NEO-FFI}}}
&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}  \\[7ex]
\hline
\endhead

\multicolumn{10}{r@{}}{\footnotesize\em Continued on following page}\\
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

%% body of longtable
[10] & & &\checkmark & & &
     & Interactive personality profiling approach
     & Test were based on subjective evidences which may lead to uncertainty.
     & In order to propose a structure for effective software team structure. \\
\hline
[20] & & & & & &\checkmark
     & Quasi-Experiment
     & This study is conducted with students which leads to ambiguity on difference in nature of students and software engineers.
     & To study the product quality, team climate and Satisfaction of software engineers. \\
\hline
[23] & &\checkmark & & & &
     & Empirical Study
     & The limitation of the study is that the questions used to examine software engineer's preference do not provide details about software engineers.
     & To find out influences among the emotional intelligence and work preferences. \\
\hline
[24] & & &\checkmark & & &
     & OR mathematical programming formulation.
     & The proposed approach is worthy in medium and small number of groups and teams. As number of groups and projects increases the proposed approach outperform.
     & This study focuses on Multiple Team Formation Problem (MTFP)\@. The proposed approach focuses on allocating multiple people to multiple groups or teams.   \\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & &
     & Empirical Study
     & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
     & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & &
     & Empirical Study
     & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
     & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & &
     & Empirical Study
     & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
     & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & &
     & Empirical Study
     & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
     & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & &
     & Empirical Study
     & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
     & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\
\hline
[25] & & & &\checkmark & &
     & Empirical Study
     & They have studied the personalities of undergraduate students in pair programming which might lead to wrong results as undergraduate students and software engineers have difference in term of personalities.
     & o study the effect of developers personalities and nature on pair programming.\\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```